# Почему не оторбражается столбец типа массив в DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

Есть таблица, в которой третий столбец имеет тип *integer array* . В postgres таблица отображается корректно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В DataGridView (WinForms) не оторбражается третий столбец, который является массивом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавление в DataGridView:

```
string sqlTID = "SELECT * FROM \"TID\"";
NpgsqlCommand cmdTID = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlTID, connect);

DataTable dtTID = new DataTable();
dtTID.Load(cmdTID.ExecuteReader());

dataGridView_TID.DataSource = null;
dataGridView_TID.DataSource = dtTID;
dataGridView_TID.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
dataGridView_TID.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
```

В чем может быть причина и как это исправить?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: `DataGridView` - контрол из какой библиотеки? WinForms? Добавьте метку. И покажите код, как добавляете данные в грид.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov изменила, спасибо за совет.

Comment: Я плохо знаю winoforms, я больше по WPF, но мне кажется что DGV просто не поддерживает отображение массивов в одной ячейке и выбрасывает колонку как несовместимую. Попробуйте создать прокси-класс с данными, представляющий строчку DGV и создать из него `List<MyClass>`. Затем просто вручную выгрузить данные из `DataTable` в этот список, попутно отконвертировав неотображаемые данные, например в `string`. Но может есть способ легче, я не знаю.

Comment: [Как в C# преобразовать `int[]` в `string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822811/int-array-to-string)